# How to send an email to user with the attached secure CSV file and email should be non-reply

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I am working in spring batch where I have the requirement to create CSV file with some business logic and it should be noneditable. I want to send the file with the domain name where the user can not reply(no-reply@domain.com).

I implemented Java mail service by using Spring-Boot starter mail. In application properties, I have set the authentication and server port. After that, I have implemented Email service and send the used JavaMailSender.
Now I want to send an email with a secure CSV file. But right now email received into the Junk box.

```
Application.yml

 mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: 
    password: 
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true  

MailService:

public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    /**
     * Send email.
     *
     * @param to the to
     * @param subject the subject
     * @param text the text
     */
    @Override
    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String text) {

        try {
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);

            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            log.info("Mail Exception {}", e);
        }


    }
```

so I have only two questions:

Q1: how can I make secure CSV file?

Q2: is it possible to send an email from a domain like(no-reply@domain.com)

Q3: how to send the email into the inbox instead of junk folder

Comment: Guys, Nothing is working. Please share the link so can I read and implement the same.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your queries:

**Q1: how can I make secure CSV file?**

CSV files are generally text files. If by secure, you mean readonly, then thats simple. All you need to do is to mark that file a [readonly](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-a-file-read-only-in-java/). But remember that, this is not full proof. The user/application receiving this file can make that file writable. If you are working about accidental modification, then making readonly should be ok.

**Q2: is it possible to send an email from a domain like(no-reply@domain.com)**

All you need to set the desired email in SimpleMailMessage ([Check here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html#setFrom-java.lang.String-))

**Q3: how to send the email into the inbox instead of junk folder**

This is a little difficult to control from the Sender Side. The email server at the receiver side decides which email domains are whitelisted (non-junk). Best you can do is to request the email receiver to whitelist your domain so that your email does not go in junk folder.

Comment: Hi Santosh. When I sent an email to the user. He still receives an editable file and it is still in the junk folder and with email id instead of no-reply@domain.com

Comment: @VimitDhawan, please check if the file is 'ReadOnly' before sending it via email. Also what did you use, _message.setReplyTo()_  or _message.setFrom()_ ?

Comment: I am using message.setFrom()

Comment: Please try using _message.setReplyTo()_.

Answer (score 0):

A1) You can't make an CSV file "secure" in general

A2) message.setReplyTo("no-reply@domain.com");

A3) This is not in your hand. This is the responsibility of the receivers email provider and their spam rules. You can't influence this.